# How can I assign a delegate for UIVideoEditorController in ReactNative when the module I am working on is just classes

Tags: ios, react-native, module, delegates, uivideoeditorcontroller

```
    func previewRecording (withFileName fileURL: String) {
        if UIVideoEditorController.canEditVideo(atPath: fileURL) {
            let rootView = UIApplication.getTopMostViewController()
            let editController = UIVideoEditorController()
            editController.videoPath = fileURL
//            editController.delegate = ?????
            rootView?.present(editController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {

        }
    }
```

^ current code

I have gone around the internet in circles a few times trying to figure this out. What would be the best approach for specifying a delegate for the UIVideoEditorController here? This is a react-native module where there is no ViewController, just utility classes.

Some simple example code I have come across

```
extension SomeViewController : 
    UIVideoEditorControllerDelegate, 
    UINavigationControllerDelegate {

  func videoEditorController(_ editor: UIVideoEditorController, 
    didSaveEditedVideoToPath editedVideoPath: String) {

    print("saved!")
  }
}
```

I am just loss about how to make this happen in my module though.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @objc class ScreenRecordCoordinator: NSObject
    {
        let previewDelegateView = PreviewDelegateView()
        // .......
        editController.delegate = previewDelegateView
    }

    class PreviewDelegateView: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIVideoEditorControllerDelegate {

        var isSaved:Bool = false

        func videoEditorController(_ editor: UIVideoEditorController, didSaveEditedVideoToPath editedVideoPath: String) {
            print("save called")
            if(!self.isSaved) {
                self.isSaved = true
                print("trimmed video saved!")
                editor.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                ReplayFileUtil.replaceItem(at: URL(fileURLWithPath: editor.videoPath), with: URL(fileURLWithPath: editedVideoPath))
                    self.isSaved = false
                })
            }
        }
    }
```